# How to handle exceptions in a JDBC ResultSet Iterator

Tags: scala

I have a couple of housekeeping and exception handling questions around processing JDBC ResultSets as Iterators (see code below -- specifically the sql function).

```scala
class SqlHelper(prop: Properties) {

  val conn = {
    Class.forName(prop.getProperty("drivername"))
    DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getProperty("jdbcurl"), prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"))
  }

  def sql(conn: Connection, s: String): Iterator[ResultSet] = {
    val rs = conn.createStatement.executeQuery(s)
    Iterator.
      continually(rs.next, rs).
      takeWhile(_._1).
      map(_._2)
  }
}
```

The caller would find work (to do) and pass it to an Akka worker actor. Once it is done, it will repeat that loop.

```scala
  def doWork = {
    val sqlhelper = new SqlHelper(new Properties())

    while (true) {
      try {
        sqlhelper.
          sql("select work_key from wip_table where need_to_process = 'Y'").
          foreach(k => worker ! Work(k.getString("work_key")))
        ?????? how to clean up after finishing ????
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          e.printStackTrace()
          ?????? how to clean up after exception ????
      }
    }
  }
```

My questions are

- housekeeping - how do I close off the resultset and the statement once I am done? I can't think of a way to close the resources in the sql iterator.
- similarly, in the caller, I would like to wrap the iterator with a try/catch so that on exception, I can close the rs and statement. But I am not sure how to do that? For example, how do I get to the rs and statement to close it??

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`scala.util.Using`](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/my-favorite-new-features-of-scala-2-13-standard-library-909a89b0da4#a032) perhaps like so

```
Using.resource(DriverManager.getConnection(...)) { conn =>
  val rs = conn.createStatement.executeQuery(s)
  Iterator
    .continually(rs.next, rs)
    .takeWhile(_._1)
    .map(_._2)
    .foreach(...)
}
```

According to `Using.resource` [docs](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html#resource[R,A](resource:R)(body:R=%3EA)(implicitreleasable:scala.util.Using.Releasable[R]):A) :

> Performs an operation using a resource, and then releases the
>   resource, even if the operation throws an exception. This method
>   behaves similarly to Java's try-with-resources.

Comment: Or use existing SQL lib